# php parse simple xml attributes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm having some trouble with an xml file, I have found all sorts of examples/guides around the web and on this site but I can't seem to see one like this:

I have an XML file like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<items item1="1" item2="2" item3="3" item4="4"/>
<items item1="1" item2="2" item3="3" item4="4"/>
<items item1="1" item2="2" item3="3" item4="4"/>
</root>
```

I've not seen the data set out like this before and when I try:

```
<?php

$obj = simplexml_load_string("sample.xml");
print_r($obj);
?>
```

I get the error:

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]: Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
```

I have run the xml file through the check at www.xmlvalidation.com and all comes back ok, am I missing something?

I am looking to be able to echo the value of the item attributes in a while loop.

Comment: is it really `<root>` at the end? not `</root>` ?

Comment: Hi, sorry this is a typo, the file I am using is correct. I will edit the post now, thanks for the quick reply –

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're attempting to load XML from a file with `simplexml_load_string()`, which expects a string input.  Instead, use `simplexml_load_file()`.

```
$obj = simplexml_load_file("sample.xml");
```

Comment: Spot on, thanks! I'm just still a bit unsure why the file is set like this, do you have any ideas? Sorry I'm still very new.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is that your closing tag on the last line should be `</root>` rather than `<root>`

Comment: Hi Andrew, sorry this is a typo, the file I am using is correct.  I will edit the post now, thanks for the quick reply

Comment: I'm looking at it now to try to find the underlying cause. Changing the end tag doesn't fix it.

Comment: Found it, `simplexml_load_string` takes a string not a file. You want `simplexml_load_file()`... I'd edit my answer except someone else beat me to it so they deserve the credit :)

Answer (score 0):

Your root tag at the end is not a closing tag. When I run this XML through the validator you mention, it fails.